# Sending to telegram the results of passing methods in a collection in Postman

Tags: automation, postman, telegram-bot, status, postman-collection-runner

I need to write a script for the Tests tab for the last method in a collection, where the method will check the code 200 status for itself and all previous executed methods. If all methods passed with a status of code 200, you should write a message with this result in the telegram. If the response code in any of the methods turned out to be different, the message to the telegram should contain: method name, response code number, description of the response code.

```
const token = '6543544022:AAGLK-QhL2pEUBfu-16yawzwfDYigj45iNd';
const chatId = '485796388'.

const token = '6543544022:AAGLK-QhL2pEUBfu-16yawzwfDYigj45iNd';
const chatId = '485796388';
let errorMessage = '';

// Check the status code for each previous executed request
for (let i = 0; i < pm.info.iteration; i++) {
  const response = pm.info.trace[i].response;

  if (response && response.code !== 200) {
    const request = pm.info.trace[i].request;
    errorMessage = `Error in previous method "${request.method} ${request.url}": № ${response.code}, ${response.status}`;
    break;
  }
}

if (errorMessage === '') {
  sendMessageToTelegram('All methods executed successfully with code 200');
} else {
  sendMessageToTelegram(errorMessage);
}

// Function to send a message to Telegram
function sendMessageToTelegram(message) {
  pm.sendRequest({
    url: `https://api.telegram.org/bot${token}/sendMessage`,
    method: 'POST',
    header: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: {
      mode: 'raw',
      raw: JSON.stringify({
        chat_id: chatId,
        text: message,
      }),
    },
  }, function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log(res.json());
    }
  });
}
```

At the moment this script sends the following response: All methods executed successfully with code 200 - in any case.

I can't figure out how to write a script so that it reacts to an error when executing a method and sends the results to telegram at the end of the collection execution.

I tried to check the status of code 200 in previous methods through the Pre-request Script tab, but that didn't help either.

I am hoping for your advice. I am still learning automation, so I would be very grateful for your help.